# What does the rel="generator" tag mean in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

In the Wordpress theme I'm using, I saw a line that said the following in the footer:

```
<a href="http://wordpress.org/" rel="generator">Proudly powered by WordPress</a>
```

What does the `rel` tag do in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the `rel` attribute [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) states:

> For anchors containing the href attribute, this attribute specifies
>   the relationship of the target object to the link object. The value is
>   a comma-separated list of [link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) values. The values and their
>   semantics will be registered by some authority that might have meaning
>   to the document author. The default relationship, if no other is
>   given, is void. Use this attribute only if the href attribute is
>   present.

[W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) adds:

> Relationship between the document containing the hyperlink and the
>   destination resource. The rel attribute has no default value. If the attribute is omitted or if none of the values in the attribute are recognized by the user agent, then the document has no particular relationship with the destination resource other than there being a hyperlink between the two.

So in your case, the rel attribute for that link is saying (to someone) that the generator of the page is WordPress, with a link provided to WordPress.org.

You might notice though, that  `generator` isn't listed as a valid link type. This causes errors when validating the page:

> Bad value generator for attribute rel on element a: The string
>   generator is not a registered keyword.

So depending on whether HTM lvalidation is important to you or not, you may want to alter or remove that attribute.